# Merging dict to into a list of lists

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a dict that like this

```
{'id':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'code':['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6'],
 'price':['35', '23', '54', '17', '68', '199'] 
}
```

How can I make it look like this:

```
data= [
    
   [0, 'A1', '35'],
   [1, 'A2', '23'],
   [2, 'A3', '54'],
   [3, 'A4', '17'],
   [4, 'A5', '68'],
   [5, 'A6', '199'],

]
```

I know that I can do it in python but just want someone to point me in the direction of how to do it, because I don't know **where** to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a transpose operation -- note that `zip()` returns an iterable of tuples, so we need to transform them to lists using `map()`:

```py
list(map(list, zip(*data.values())))
```

This outputs:

```py
[[0, 'A1', '35'], [1, 'A2', '23'], [2, 'A3', '54'], [3, 'A4', '17'], [4, 'A5', '68'], [5, 'A6', '199']]
```

Comment: @XxJames07- why?